# How to save a dictionary and a list in the same json file with python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I wish to save a dictionary and a list in one json file so that when I parse the file I could distinguish them.
This is the function I use to save the dictionary in the json file:

```
def save_callback():
    #folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    with open(file,'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(test_dict))
    os.rename(file.name,file.name + ".txt")
```

What should I add to this function to save the list too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JSON objects can be arbitrarily nested, the easiest solution is to store both the dict and the list inside another object:

```
data = json.dumps([test_dict, test_list])
```

Then you can load it like this:

```
test_dict, test_list = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: The first part worked but the load  returns an error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: @evgeny You're not giving it the data, you give it a file. If you wish to give a file, use `json.load(file)`. (Notice the lack of `s` denoting a string).